# Regex required to extract alphabets and numbers and return an array

Tags: regex

Need a regex to get alphabets and numbers. Examples below:

```
input1 - CCG [50 %]       output1 CCG, 50
input2 - CCG old [59.6%]  output2 CCG old, 59.6
inout3 - NSG [65.43%]     output3 NSG, 65.43
```

I am using the function string split. This will convert string into array of length two which will fit my requirement.

My requirement is to pass the regex in split() function.

```
split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)")
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Without more details, like what the `split` does, I can only suggest `(?<=[A-Za-z])\s+\[|%\]$`. However, I am not even sure you may use a lookbehind, or whether empty matches are dropped.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
<?php

$string = 'CCG [50 %]
CCG old [59.6%]
NSG [65.43%]';
$pattern = '/(.+?)\s\[(\d+?)(\.?)(\d*?)(\s?)%\]/im';
$replacement = '${1}, ${2}${3}${4}';

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

The result:

```
CCG, 50
CCG old, 59.6
NSG, 65.43
```

Answer (score 0):

Wat you might do to match the parts to split on is to either match either:

- `\[(?=\d)` a whitespace, and opening bracket and assert that what follows is a digit
- or `|`
- `?%]$` match an optional whitespace, a `%` and an closing bracket at the end of the line

[`\[(?=\d)| ?%]$`](https://regex101.com/r/XI3oBX/1/)

As an alternative to use split, you might match what you want to remove and capture what you want to keep in the first capturing group.

In the replacement you could then use a coma followed by a whitespace and then group 1.

**Match**

[`\[(\d+[. ]\d*)%\]`](https://regex101.com/r/hrq1VJ/1)

**Replacement**

`, $1`